# stripping centos packages to the basics

Tags: centos6

I am stripping a centos sever to bare bones as I would like to start basic. I have yum removed packages I won't be using (php, ruby, PostgreSQL, Webmin, Usermin, Mail, Awstats...)

I am looking to be left with things like Apache, node.js, security, mysql.

Do I need perl (I'm not going to code in it)? Also samba and talk? I've removed about a 3rd of the non-essential so far but I am having trouble identifying some.

What else can I remove to simplify?

note: * marks things I know I need, ? marks things that I am wondering the point of

```
? GeoIP.x86_64
MAKEDEV.x86_64
acl.x86_64
apr.x86_64
apr-util.x86_64
apr-util-ldap.x86_64
aspell.x86_64
attr.x86_64
audit-libs.x86_64
authconfig.x86_64
* autoconf.noarch
* automake.noarch
avahi-libs.x86_64
basesystem.noarch
bash.x86_64
bind.x86_64
bind-libs.x86_64
bind-utils.x86_64
binutils.x86_64
bzip2.x86_64
bzip2-libs.i686
bzip2-libs.x86_64
c-ares19.x86_64
c-ares19-devel.x86_64
ca-certificates.noarch
* cairo.x86_64
* cairo-devel.x86_64
* cairomm.x86_64
* cairomm-devel.x86_64
centos-indexhtml.noarch
centos-release.x86_64
* checkpolicy.x86_64
chkconfig.x86_64
cloog-ppl.x86_64
compat-readline5.x86_64
coreutils.x86_64
coreutils-libs.x86_64
cpio.x86_64
cpp.x86_64
cracklib.x86_64
cracklib-dicts.x86_64
cronie.x86_64
cronie-noanacron.x86_64
crontabs.noarch
cups-libs.x86_64
curl.x86_64
cyrus-sasl.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-gssapi.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-md5.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-plain.x86_64
? db4.x86_64
? db4-cxx.x86_64
? db4-devel.x86_64
? db4-utils.x86_64
dbus-glib.x86_64
dbus-libs.x86_64
dhclient.x86_64
dhcp-common.x86_64
diffutils.x86_64
? docbook-dtds.noarch         //some pdf tool?
? docbook-style-dsssl.noarch
? docbook-style-xsl.noarch 
? docbook-utils.noarch
e2fsprogs.x86_64
e2fsprogs-libs.i686
e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64
ed.x86_64
elfutils.x86_64
elfutils-libelf.x86_64
elfutils-libs.x86_64
epel-release.noarch
ethtool.x86_64
expat.x86_64
file-libs.x86_64
filesystem.x86_64
findutils.x86_64
? finger.x86_64
? finger-server.x86_64
fipscheck.x86_64
fipscheck-lib.x86_64
fontconfig.x86_64
fontconfig-devel.x86_64
freetype.x86_64
freetype-devel.x86_64
ftp.x86_64
gamin.i686
gamin.x86_64
gawk.x86_64
gcc.x86_64
gcc-c++.x86_64
gd.x86_64
gdbm.x86_64
gdbm-devel.x86_64
giflib.x86_64
giflib-devel.x86_64
glib2.i686
glib2.x86_64
glib2-devel.x86_64
glibc.i686
glibc.x86_64
glibc-common.x86_64
glibc-devel.x86_64
glibc-headers.x86_64
glibmm24.x86_64
gmp.x86_64
gnupg2.x86_64
gnutls.x86_64
gpgme.x86_64
gpm-libs.x86_64
grep.x86_64
groff.x86_64
gtk-doc.noarch
gyp.noarch
gzip.x86_64
hesiod.x86_64
http-parser.x86_64
http-parser-devel.x86_64
httpd-tools.x86_64
hwdata.noarch
info.x86_64
initscripts.x86_64
iproute.x86_64
* iptables.x86_64
iputils.x86_64
? jwhois.x86_64
kernel-headers.x86_64
keyutils-libs.x86_64
keyutils-libs-devel.x86_64
krb5-devel.x86_64
krb5-libs.x86_64
? less.x86_64
libICE.x86_64
libSM.x86_64
libX11.x86_64
libX11-common.noarch
libX11-devel.x86_64
libXau.x86_64
libXau-devel.x86_64
libXext.x86_64
libXext-devel.x86_64
libXft.x86_64
libXft-devel.x86_64
libXpm.x86_64
libXrender.x86_64
libXrender-devel.x86_64
libacl.i686
libacl.x86_64
libattr.i686
libattr.x86_64
libblkid.x86_64
libc-client.x86_64
libcap.x86_64
libcap-ng.x86_64
libcom_err.i686
libcom_err.x86_64
libcom_err-devel.x86_64
libcurl.x86_64
libedit.x86_64
libffi.x86_64
libgcc.i686
libgcc.x86_64
libgcrypt.x86_64
libgomp.x86_64
libgpg-error.x86_64
libgssglue.x86_64
libicu.x86_64
libidn.x86_64
* libjpeg-turbo.x86_64
* libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64
libnih.x86_64
libnl.x86_64
libpcap.x86_64
* libpng.i686
* libpng.x86_64
* libpng-devel.x86_64
libproxy.x86_64
libproxy-bin.x86_64
libproxy-python.x86_64
libselinux.i686
libselinux.x86_64
libselinux-devel.x86_64
libselinux-utils.x86_64
libsemanage.x86_64
libsepol.x86_64
libsepol-devel.x86_64
libsigc++20.x86_64
libsigc++20-devel.x86_64
libss.x86_64
libssh2.x86_64
libstdc++.i686
libstdc++.x86_64
libstdc++-devel.x86_64
libtalloc.x86_64
libtasn1.x86_64
libtdb.x86_64
libtevent.x86_64
? libthai.x86_64
libtiff.x86_64
* libtirpc.x86_64
libtool-ltdl.x86_64
libusb.x86_64
libuser.x86_64
libutempter.x86_64
libuuid.x86_64
libuv.x86_64
libuv-devel.x86_64
libxcb.x86_64
libxcb-devel.x86_64
libxml2.i686
libxml2.x86_64
libxslt.x86_64
lm_sensors-libs.x86_64
logrotate.x86_64
lsof.x86_64
lua.x86_64
lynx.x86_64
m4.x86_64
* make.x86_64
man.x86_64
man-pages.noarch
mingetty.x86_64
mlocate.x86_64
module-init-tools.x86_64
mpfr.x86_64
* mysql.x86_64
* mysql-devel.x86_64
* mysql-libs.x86_64
* mysql-server.x86_64
* nano.x86_64
ncompress.x86_64
ncurses.x86_64
ncurses-base.x86_64
ncurses-libs.i686
ncurses-libs.x86_64
neon.x86_64
net-snmp.x86_64
net-snmp-libs.x86_64
net-snmp-utils.x86_64
net-tools.x86_64
newt.x86_64
newt-python.x86_64
* node-gyp.noarch                all node is *
nodejs.x86_64
nodejs-abbrev.noarch
nodejs-ansi.noarch
nodejs-archy.noarch
nodejs-asn1.noarch
nodejs-assert-plus.noarch
nodejs-async.noarch
nodejs-aws-sign.noarch
nodejs-block-stream.noarch
nodejs-boom.noarch
nodejs-child-process-close.noarch
nodejs-chmodr.noarch
nodejs-chownr.noarch
nodejs-cmd-shim.noarch
nodejs-combined-stream.noarch
nodejs-config-chain.noarch
nodejs-cookie-jar.noarch
nodejs-couch-login.noarch
nodejs-cryptiles.noarch
nodejs-ctype.noarch
nodejs-delayed-stream.noarch
nodejs-devel.x86_64
nodejs-editor.noarch
nodejs-forever-agent.noarch
nodejs-form-data.noarch
nodejs-fstream.noarch
nodejs-fstream-ignore.noarch
nodejs-fstream-npm.noarch
nodejs-github-url-from-git.noarch
nodejs-glob.noarch
nodejs-graceful-fs.noarch
nodejs-hawk.noarch
nodejs-hoek.noarch
nodejs-http-signature.noarch
nodejs-inherits.noarch
nodejs-ini.noarch
nodejs-init-package-json.noarch
nodejs-json-stringify-safe.noarch
nodejs-lockfile.noarch
nodejs-lru-cache.noarch
nodejs-mime.noarch
nodejs-minimatch.noarch
nodejs-mkdirp.noarch
nodejs-mute-stream.noarch
nodejs-node-uuid.noarch
nodejs-nopt.noarch
nodejs-normalize-package-data.noarch
nodejs-npm-registry-client.noarch
nodejs-npm-user-validate.noarch
nodejs-npmconf.noarch
nodejs-npmlog.noarch
nodejs-oauth-sign.noarch
nodejs-once.noarch
nodejs-opener.noarch
nodejs-osenv.noarch
nodejs-packaging.noarch
nodejs-promzard.noarch
nodejs-proto-list.noarch
nodejs-qs.noarch
nodejs-read.noarch
nodejs-read-installed.noarch
nodejs-read-package-json.noarch
nodejs-request.noarch
nodejs-retry.noarch
nodejs-rimraf.noarch
nodejs-semver.noarch
nodejs-sha.noarch
nodejs-sigmund.noarch
nodejs-slide.noarch
nodejs-sntp.noarch
nodejs-tar.noarch
nodejs-tunnel-agent.noarch
nodejs-uid-number.noarch
nodejs-which.noarch
* npm.noarch
nscd.x86_64
nspr.x86_64
nss.x86_64
nss-softokn.x86_64
nss-softokn-freebl.i686
nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64
nss-sysinit.x86_64
nss-tools.x86_64
nss-util.x86_64
ntsysv.x86_64
? openjade.x86_64
openldap.x86_64
opensp.x86_64
* openssh.x86_64
* openssh-clients.x86_64
* openssh-server.x86_64
* openssl.x86_64
* openssl-devel.x86_64
p11-kit.x86_64
p11-kit-trust.x86_64
pakchois.x86_64
pam.x86_64
* pango.x86_64
* pango-devel.x86_64
* pangomm.x86_64
passwd.x86_64
pcre.x86_64
? perl.x86_64
? perl-Archive-Tar.x86_64
? perl-BSD-Resource.x86_64
? perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64
? perl-Compress-Zlib.x86_64
? perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-Bignum.x86_64         Im using node-forge for crypto security
? perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA.x86_64
? perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-Random.x86_64
? perl-Crypt-SSLeay.x86_64
? perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64
? perl-DBI.x86_64
? perl-Digest-HMAC.noarch
? perl-Digest-SHA.x86_64
? perl-Digest-SHA1.x86_64
? perl-Encode-Detect.x86_64
? perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker.x86_64
? perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS.x86_64
? perl-HTML-Parser.x86_64
? perl-HTML-Tagset.noarch
? perl-IO-Compress-Base.x86_64
? perl-IO-Compress-Zlib.x86_64
? perl-IO-Socket-INET6.noarch
? perl-IO-Socket-SSL.noarch
? perl-IO-Tty.x86_64
? perl-IO-Zlib.x86_64
? perl-Mail-DKIM.noarch
? perl-MailTools.noarch
? perl-Module-Pluggable.x86_64
? perl-Net-DNS.x86_64
? perl-Net-LibIDN.x86_64
? perl-Net-SSLeay.x86_64
? perl-NetAddr-IP.x86_64
? perl-Package-Constants.x86_64
? perl-Pod-Escapes.x86_64
? perl-Pod-Simple.x86_64
? perl-SGMLSpm.noarch
? perl-Socket6.x86_64
? perl-Test-Harness.x86_64
? perl-Time-HiRes.x86_64
? perl-TimeDate.noarch
? perl-URI.noarch
? perl-devel.x86_64
? perl-libs.x86_64
? perl-version.x86_64
pinentry.x86_64
* pixman.x86_64
* pixman-devel.x86_64
pkgconfig.x86_64
policycoreutils.x86_64
popt.x86_64
portreserve.x86_64
postfix.x86_64
ppl.x86_64
procps.x86_64
* proftpd.x86_64
psmisc.x86_64
pth.x86_64
pygpgme.x86_64
python.x86_64
* python-iniparse.noarch
* python-libs.x86_64
* python-pycurl.x86_64
* python-urlgrabber.noarch
quota.x86_64
rarian.x86_64
rarian-compat.x86_64
readline.x86_64
redhat-logos.noarch
redhat-rpm-config.noarch
remi-release.noarch
rootfiles.noarch
rpcbind.x86_64
rpm.x86_64
rpm-libs.x86_64
rpm-python.x86_64
rsync.x86_64
rsyslog.x86_64
? samba.x86_64
? samba-client.x86_64
? samba-common.x86_64
? samba-winbind.x86_64
? samba-winbind-clients.x86_64
* screen.x86_64
sed.x86_64
setup.noarch
setuptool.x86_64
sgml-common.noarch
shadow-utils.x86_64
shared-mime-info.x86_64
slang.x86_64
sqlite.x86_64
stunnel.x86_64
subversion.x86_64
sysvinit-tools.x86_64
? talk.x86_64
? talk-server.x86_64
* tar.x86_64
tcp_wrappers.x86_64
tcp_wrappers-libs.x86_64
tcpdump.x86_64
tcsh.x86_64
telnet.x86_64
time.x86_64
tmpwatch.x86_64
traceroute.x86_64
tzdata.noarch
udev.x86_64
unixODBC.x86_64
* unzip.x86_64
* upstart.x86_64
usermode.x86_64
ustr.x86_64
util-linux-ng.x86_64
v8.x86_64
v8-devel.x86_64
vzdev.noarch
vzdummy-glibc.noarch
vzdummy-init-fc13.noarch
* wget.x86_64
which.x86_64
xinetd.x86_64
xml-common.noarch
xorg-x11-proto-devel.noarch
xz.x86_64
xz-libs.i686
xz-libs.x86_64
xz-lzma-compat.x86_64
* yum.noarch
* yum-metadata-parser.x86_64
* yum-plugin-fastestmirror.noarch
zlib.i686
zlib.x86_64
zlib-devel.x86_64
```

Comment: It's better to _start_ with a minimal installation and then add only the packages you need.

Comment: I did know that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to go through the list because I don't know (and really don't want to know) what you're doing with the system.

Only you can really decide if a package is required by your business needs or not.

You are aided somewhat by the package management system try `yum remove perl` and see what it says, see what it's going to remove because of dependencies, be surprised and leave it alone.

It may be easier to [start small](http://centos.openitc.uk/6.5/isos/x86_64/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso) and add stuff you need.

Answer (score 0):

Uhhh, why didn't you start with the minimal install? Maybe strip that down a bit more and then add what you actually need?

RHEL/CentOS has some odd dependancies at least last time I stripped it down to the bare essentials, but minimal is already pretty good.

Comment: my host does not provide that option